# How can I reduce the amount of GPU used by my tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, unet-neural-network

So I am currently using the Kaggle notebook environment. I am trying to build a U-Net model for image segmentation. When I build the model, it shows that the mode size is 2.17mb, but this takes model takes up 15.4GB of the GPU memory. Why is this happening? Is there any way I can reduce this? Does building the model using pytorch help with this? I am kinda new to this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the code for my model for reproducibility.

```
def build_ARes_UNet(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDHT, IMG_CHANNELS, FILTER_NUM, FILTER_SIZE, DROPOUT, ACTIVATION, RESIDUAL, ATTENTION):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_WIDHT, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS))
    # s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x/255)(inputs)
    #layer 1
    c1 = res_conv_block(x=inputs, size=FILTER_NUM, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #16 FOR FITLER_NUM=16
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

    #layer 2
    c2 = res_conv_block(x=p1, size=FILTER_NUM*2, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #32
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

    #layer 3
    c3 = res_conv_block(x=p2, size=FILTER_NUM*4, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #64
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

    #layer 4
    c4 = res_conv_block(x=p3, size=FILTER_NUM*8, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #128
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
     
    #layer 5
    c5 = Conv2D(FILTER_NUM*16, (3, 3), activation='relu',  padding='same')(p4) #256
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(FILTER_NUM*16, (3, 3), activation='relu',  padding='same')(c5)

    #Expansive path 
    #layer 6
    u6 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), data_format="channels_last")(c5)
    if ATTENTION[0]:
        gate6 = gate_block(c5, FILTER_NUM*8) #128
        attention6 = attention_block(c4, gate6, FILTER_NUM*8)
        # u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
        u6 = concatenate([u6, attention6], axis=3)
    else:
        u6 = concatenate([u6,c4])
    c6 = res_conv_block(x=u6, size=FILTER_NUM*8, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #128
     
    #layer 7 
    u7 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), data_format="channels_last")(c6)
    if ATTENTION[1]:
        gate7 = gate_block(c6, FILTER_NUM*4)
        attention7 = attention_block(c3, gate7, FILTER_NUM*4)
        # u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
        u7 = concatenate([u7, attention7])
    else:
        u7 = concatenate([u7,c3])
    c7 = res_conv_block(x=u7, size=FILTER_NUM*4, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #64
    
    #layer 8 
    u8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), data_format="channels_last")(c7)
    if ATTENTION[2]:
        gate8 = gate_block(c7, FILTER_NUM*2)
        attention8 = attention_block(c2, gate8, FILTER_NUM*2)  
        # u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
        u8 = concatenate([u8, attention8])
    else:
        u8 = concatenate([u8,c2])
    c8 = res_conv_block(x=u8, size=FILTER_NUM*2, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #32
    
    #layer 9
    u9 = UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), data_format="channels_last")(c8)
    if ATTENTION[3]:
        gate9 = gate_block(c8, FILTER_NUM)
        attention9 = attention_block(c1, gate9, FILTER_NUM)
        # u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
        u9 = concatenate([u9, attention9], axis=3)
    else:
        u9 = concatenate([u9,c1])
    c9 = res_conv_block(x=u9, size=FILTER_NUM, f_size=FILTER_SIZE, dropout=DROPOUT, activation=ACTIVATION, res=RESIDUAL) #16
     
    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding = 'same')(c9)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model
```

The definition of the res_conv_block is as follows:

```
def res_conv_block(x, size, f_size, dropout, activation, res):
    c1 = Conv2D(size,(f_size, f_size), padding='same',activation=activation)(x)
    c1 = Dropout(dropout)(c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(size,(f_size, f_size), padding='same', activation=activation)(c1)

    if not res:
        return c1
    else: 
        shortcut = Conv2D(size, kernel_size = (1,1), padding ='same')(x)

        respath = tf.keras.layers.Add()([shortcut, c1])
        respath = Activation(activation)(c1)

        return respath
```

The Output of my model summary is as follows:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)        ┃ Output Shape      ┃    Param # ┃ Connected to      ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer         │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ -                 │
│ (InputLayer)        │ 3)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d (Conv2D)     │ (None, 256, 256,  │        224 │ input_layer[0][0] │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout (Dropout)   │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ conv2d[0][0]      │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_1 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 256, 256,  │        584 │ dropout[0][0]     │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation          │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ conv2d_1[0][0]    │
│ (Activation)        │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d       │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ activation[0][0]  │
│ (MaxPooling2D)      │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_3 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 128, 128,  │      1,168 │ max_pooling2d[0]… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_1 (Dropout) │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_3[0][0]    │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_4 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 128, 128,  │      2,320 │ dropout_1[0][0]   │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_1        │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_4[0][0]    │
│ (Activation)        │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d_1     │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ activation_1[0][… │
│ (MaxPooling2D)      │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_6 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 64, 64,    │      4,640 │ max_pooling2d_1[… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_2 (Dropout) │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ conv2d_6[0][0]    │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_7 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 64, 64,    │      9,248 │ dropout_2[0][0]   │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_2        │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ conv2d_7[0][0]    │
│ (Activation)        │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d_2     │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ activation_2[0][… │
│ (MaxPooling2D)      │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_9 (Conv2D)   │ (None, 32, 32,    │     18,496 │ max_pooling2d_2[… │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_3 (Dropout) │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_9[0][0]    │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_10 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │     36,928 │ dropout_3[0][0]   │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_3        │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_10[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d_3     │ (None, 16, 16,    │          0 │ activation_3[0][… │
│ (MaxPooling2D)      │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_12 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16,    │     73,856 │ max_pooling2d_3[… │
│                     │ 128)              │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_4 (Dropout) │ (None, 16, 16,    │          0 │ conv2d_12[0][0]   │
│                     │ 128)              │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_13 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16,    │    147,584 │ dropout_4[0][0]   │
│                     │ 128)              │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_14 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16,    │      8,256 │ conv2d_13[0][0]   │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_16 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16,    │      4,160 │ conv2d_14[0][0]   │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose    │ (None, 16, 16,    │     36,928 │ conv2d_16[0][0]   │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)   │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_15 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16,    │      4,160 │ activation_3[0][… │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ add_4 (Add)         │ (None, 16, 16,    │          0 │ conv2d_transpose… │
│                     │ 64)               │            │ conv2d_15[0][0]   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_4        │ (None, 16, 16,    │          0 │ add_4[0][0]       │
│ (Activation)        │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_17 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 16, 16, 1) │         65 │ activation_4[0][… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_5        │ (None, 16, 16, 1) │          0 │ conv2d_17[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_1     │ (None, 32, 32, 1) │          0 │ activation_5[0][… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ lambda (Lambda)     │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ up_sampling2d_1[… │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ multiply (Multiply) │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ lambda[0][0],     │
│                     │ 64)               │            │ activation_3[0][… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_18 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │      4,160 │ multiply[0][0]    │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d       │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_13[0][0]   │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 128)              │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ batch_normalization │ (None, 32, 32,    │        256 │ conv2d_18[0][0]   │
│ (BatchNormalizatio… │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate         │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ up_sampling2d[0]… │
│ (Concatenate)       │ 192)              │            │ batch_normalizat… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_19 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │    110,656 │ concatenate[0][0] │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_5 (Dropout) │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_19[0][0]   │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_20 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │     36,928 │ dropout_5[0][0]   │
│                     │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_6        │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_20[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_22 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │      2,080 │ activation_6[0][… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_24 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │      1,056 │ conv2d_22[0][0]   │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_1  │ (None, 32, 32,    │      9,248 │ conv2d_24[0][0]   │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)   │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_23 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32,    │      1,056 │ activation_2[0][… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ add_6 (Add)         │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ conv2d_transpose… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │ conv2d_23[0][0]   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_7        │ (None, 32, 32,    │          0 │ add_6[0][0]       │
│ (Activation)        │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_25 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 32, 32, 1) │         33 │ activation_7[0][… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_8        │ (None, 32, 32, 1) │          0 │ conv2d_25[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_3     │ (None, 64, 64, 1) │          0 │ activation_8[0][… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ lambda_1 (Lambda)   │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ up_sampling2d_3[… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ multiply_1          │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ lambda_1[0][0],   │
│ (Multiply)          │ 32)               │            │ activation_2[0][… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_26 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │      1,056 │ multiply_1[0][0]  │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_2     │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ activation_6[0][… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 64)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ batch_normalizatio… │ (None, 64, 64,    │        128 │ conv2d_26[0][0]   │
│ (BatchNormalizatio… │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_1       │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ up_sampling2d_2[… │
│ (Concatenate)       │ 96)               │            │ batch_normalizat… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_27 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │     27,680 │ concatenate_1[0]… │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_6 (Dropout) │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ conv2d_27[0][0]   │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_28 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │      9,248 │ dropout_6[0][0]   │
│                     │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_9        │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ conv2d_28[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_30 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │        528 │ activation_9[0][… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_32 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │        272 │ conv2d_30[0][0]   │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_2  │ (None, 64, 64,    │      2,320 │ conv2d_32[0][0]   │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)   │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_31 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64,    │        272 │ activation_1[0][… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ add_8 (Add)         │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ conv2d_transpose… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │ conv2d_31[0][0]   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_10       │ (None, 64, 64,    │          0 │ add_8[0][0]       │
│ (Activation)        │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_33 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 64, 64, 1) │         17 │ activation_10[0]… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_11       │ (None, 64, 64, 1) │          0 │ conv2d_33[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_5     │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ activation_11[0]… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 1)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ lambda_2 (Lambda)   │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ up_sampling2d_5[… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ multiply_2          │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ lambda_2[0][0],   │
│ (Multiply)          │ 16)               │            │ activation_1[0][… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_34 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │        272 │ multiply_2[0][0]  │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_4     │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ activation_9[0][… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 32)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ batch_normalizatio… │ (None, 128, 128,  │         64 │ conv2d_34[0][0]   │
│ (BatchNormalizatio… │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_2       │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ up_sampling2d_4[… │
│ (Concatenate)       │ 48)               │            │ batch_normalizat… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_35 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │      6,928 │ concatenate_2[0]… │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_7 (Dropout) │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_35[0][0]   │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_36 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │      2,320 │ dropout_7[0][0]   │
│                     │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_12       │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_36[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_38 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │        136 │ activation_12[0]… │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_40 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │         72 │ conv2d_38[0][0]   │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_transpose_3  │ (None, 128, 128,  │        584 │ conv2d_40[0][0]   │
│ (Conv2DTranspose)   │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_39 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │         72 │ activation[0][0]  │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ add_10 (Add)        │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_transpose… │
│                     │ 8)                │            │ conv2d_39[0][0]   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_13       │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ add_10[0][0]      │
│ (Activation)        │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_41 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 128, 128,  │          9 │ activation_13[0]… │
│                     │ 1)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_14       │ (None, 128, 128,  │          0 │ conv2d_41[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 1)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_7     │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ activation_14[0]… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 1)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ lambda_3 (Lambda)   │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ up_sampling2d_7[… │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ multiply_3          │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ lambda_3[0][0],   │
│ (Multiply)          │ 8)                │            │ activation[0][0]  │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_42 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 256, 256,  │         72 │ multiply_3[0][0]  │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ up_sampling2d_6     │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ activation_12[0]… │
│ (UpSampling2D)      │ 16)               │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ batch_normalizatio… │ (None, 256, 256,  │         32 │ conv2d_42[0][0]   │
│ (BatchNormalizatio… │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ concatenate_3       │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ up_sampling2d_6[… │
│ (Concatenate)       │ 24)               │            │ batch_normalizat… │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_43 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 256, 256,  │      1,736 │ concatenate_3[0]… │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ dropout_8 (Dropout) │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ conv2d_43[0][0]   │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_44 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 256, 256,  │        584 │ dropout_8[0][0]   │
│                     │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_15       │ (None, 256, 256,  │          0 │ conv2d_44[0][0]   │
│ (Activation)        │ 8)                │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ conv2d_46 (Conv2D)  │ (None, 256, 256,  │          9 │ activation_15[0]… │
│                     │ 1)                │            │                   │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┘
 Total params: 568,501 (2.17 MB)
 Trainable params: 568,261 (2.17 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 240 (960.00 B)
```

This is my memory usage as shown by Kaggle:
[Link To Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Zi5.png)

My Images are of the dimension 256x256x3 and I am using Adam optimizer with learning rate 0.001, as follows:

```
model_ATEST = build_ARes_UNet(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDHT, IMG_CHANNELS, FILTER_NUM=8, FILTER_SIZE=3, DROPOUT=0.2, ACTIVATION='relu', RESIDUAL=1, ATTENTION=[1,1,1,1])

model_ATEST.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.001), loss=dice_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

model_ATEST.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `TensorFlow` takes all the GPU memory it can get to work a bit faster and not allocate it bit-by-bit. If you don't share the GPU or don't need it for other tasks, it should be fine.
There is an option to disable that behaviour and let TF allocate only what it needs, take a look at [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth). The important line is [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth). From the docs:

```py
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')  # get a list of gpus
try:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)  # set the growth for the first one
except:
  # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
  pass
```

If you only have one GPU available, that will do it. Othwise, you can loop through the `physical_devices` list and set the growth for every gpu.